# not able to configure https in amazon aws ec2 instance. domain hosted in godddy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i am having node js application which i am installing in aws ec2 instance. and it hosted properly.

i am created a A record in godaddy domain like api.domain.com and points the EC2 ip in there.

now application is running in api.domain.com but now i want to configure ssl there which i am not able to do so. 
any help will be deeply appreciated.

i tried everything bit no avail

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you searched for an answer on how to set up SSL?  You say you've tried everything but I see nothing.

Comment: @stdunbar i am new in this but i hosted my subdomain which point aws ec2. but now i am confused what i do to redirect that ec32 instance to https://subdomain.domain.com